# Open an Excel workbook and execute an ActiveX command button inside of an Application Server VM

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am not a strong coder (but trying to become a strong one) and was wondering if anyone has any experience in writing a VBScript to OPEN an Excel Workbook (in Application Server VM) and execute an ActiveX Command Button (e.g., commandbutton_Click()).

I got all the way to opening the Excel workbook but am stuck at executing the ActiveX Command Button.

```
Option Explicit 



'Dim pc, iMsg, iConf, Flds

Dim szHostName
Dim objExcel

Set objExcel = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")


'get the computer name
szHostName = objExcel.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )  

Call Test1()
Call SendAlertEmail(szHostName, "john.doe@corp.com", "test alert <no-reply@corp.com","Test E-mail Subject", "Test e-mail body")

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit

    'objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit



'====================================================================================================


Public Sub Test1()


Dim objWorkbook

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("E:\testfolder\test.xlsm", 0, False)

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.Run "test.xlsm!Summary.cmdCycle_Click()"




End Sub
'/////////////////////////////////////////////




' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- SendAlertEmail routine--------------------------------Start
Public Sub SendAlertEmail(ByVal servername, ByVal tostr, ByVal fromstr, ByVal subjectstr, ByVal bodystr)
    Dim pc, iMsg, iConf, Flds
Set pc = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConf.Fields

    Const schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
    Dim emailBody

    Flds.Item(schema & "sendusing") = 2
    Flds.Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "relay.exelonds.com"
    Flds.Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = 25
    Flds.Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = 0
    Flds.Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = 0
    Flds.Update()

    With iMsg
        .To = tostr
        .From = fromstr
        .Subject = servername & ":" & subjectstr

        emailBody = bodystr

        .HTMLBody = emailBody
        .Sender = "Morning Report <noreply@corp.com>"
        .Organization = "ABC Corporation"
        .ReplyTo = "noreply@corp.com"

        .Configuration = iConf

        .Send()
    End With

    ' Release Interfaces
    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iConf = Nothing
    Set Flds = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: vbscript != vba. which is it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
Dim sheetName$
sheetName = "Name of your worksheet"  '# MODIFY THIS LINE
xlBook.Application.run "'" & xlBook.Name & "'!" & sheetName & ".cmdCycle_Click"
```

Comment: I am getting an Error message that states: "Cannot run the macro "Morning Reprt.xlsm'!Summary.cmdCycle_Click'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.                              

When I open the workbook normally in the VM and execute the command button it works fine so i know that the macro exists but the script doesnt think so.

Comment: FYI, I am writing this code in VBScript, not the ActiveX command button macro in my workbook.